# Base 64 loop for html

Tags: html, base64, infinite-loop, offline

How can I ensure that the Base64 code of 'jobs.html' is embedded in 'index.html', while also having the Base64 code of 'index.html' present in 'jobs.html'? I aim to create this linkage to seamlessly navigate infinitely between the pages without encountering an endpoint

german:
Wie kann ich sicherstellen, dass der Base64-Code von 'jobs.html' in 'index.html' eingebettet wird, während gleichzeitig der Base64-Code von 'index.html' in 'jobs.html' vorhanden sein soll? Ich möchte diese Verknüpfung so gestalten, dass ich unendlich zwischen den Seiten wechseln kann, ohne dabei ein Ende zu erreichen

I tried converting the code of 'index.html' and 'jobs.html' into Base64 and then inserting each into the other, but it didn't work.

german:
Ich habe versucht, den Code von 'index.html' und 'jobs.html' in Base64 zu konvertieren und dann in den jeweils anderen Code einzufügen, aber das hat nicht funktioniert.

Comment: you could use an iframe, then just navigate to the jobs or other page...

Comment: this way your parent page which has the iframe will stay the same and wont change, but the iframe can be navigated infinitly

Comment: Can you give me an example for the iframe because I don't know how this should work